# Space character within conversion specifier

Tags: string

```
NOW=$(date +%Y_%m_%d.%H:%M:%S)
echo "NOW: $NOW"
```

The goal is to replace the `.` between the `d` and `%` character with a space.  How is this performed?  Replacing the `.` with the space character produces and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using any of the standard quoting mechanisms:

```
NOW=$(date "+%Y_%m_%d %H:%M:%S")
```

or

```
NOW=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d %H:%M:%S')
```

or

```
NOW=$(date +%Y_%m_%d\ %H:%M:%S)
```